# Detecting if app loaded from a page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So my app is (mostly) running. This is a corporate app, that our clients will 'install' on their own Facebook page(s), and make available for THEIR clients to run. During the connection process, I use the FB UID to determine their account on our system, connect that UID to the local account ID. I save that connection in our database, so that when the app is triggered from a Facebook account, I use that mapping to access the correct data.

First issue: I want to be able to detect that the app is being triggered from a Facebook page. I went into the App Settings page, and set up the "Page Tab" platform, with a secure URL. But when my app is added to a page tab, that URL is not invoked, but the Secure Canvas URL is invoked. Why? I assumed that was the point of having a Secure Page Tab URL for my app.

But if that doesn't work, is there a way to identify that my app was invoked from the Page Tab instead of some other way? Not as clean, but that would word as well.

I have used the Javascript API to login, and connect the App to a page. This is all working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in the [Page Tab App documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs#integrating):

> When a user selects your Page Tab, their browser will send a HTTP POST
>   request to your app's Secure Page Tab URL. This request will contain a
>   Signed Request in the signed_request parameter with fields you can use
>   to customise the content returned to the user.

If you're seeing the 'wrong' url triggered, make sure you're not accidentally redirecting, either upon receiving the initial POST request from the user's browser, or after using Facebook Login (e.g. if your redirect_uri when opening the dialog is accidentally sending all users to the same URL after login instead of back to where they triggered the flow from)

Comment: Thanks, that did it - it was redirecting, so quick I didn't catch it at first.